# Crop and capture screen software/plugin for Windows 7

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, browser, screen-capture

Does anyone know of any software or a browser extension that lets me capture what's on my screen and crop it by ratio?

I have Photoshop but don't want to keep opening it just to capture a simple image, crop it, and save it. I want to be able to quickly select a portion on my screen and save it. If it's possible it should let me crop by ratio (e.g. 4:3).

I will mostly be capturing in my browser - either Chrome or Firefox - but I can't find a good extension that meets my requirements.

Comment: This is what I use, although it can't crop by aspect ratio: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/abduction/. The X-Ray feature uses the DOM to intelligently select specific elements of the page, making it easier to capture precisely what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [ZScreen](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/)? It is highly configurable.  I like the ability to have the capture image automatically appear in a lightweight editor before saving/copying.  You can crop, etc. in this editor.

[image]

It uses the same editor as Greenshot, which is another alternative to purchasing SnagIt.

Comment: yeah, i really like zScreen, It's perfect. the hotkeys for crop shot works like charm, it made my life easy. This App read my mind. Thanks jrm82. You guys here in SU are all awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did something crazy the other day.  I bought software!  Tech Smith has a new version of Snagit that is outstanding.  Their revisions and improvements are fantastic (like auto saving to a library, all in one capture, video capture, etc).  It runs in the background, does not consume much memory and I assigned a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl, shift + A), so at any time with my left hand I can capture anything in an instant.

Rich

Comment: great app, it isn't free though.. :)

Comment: You get what you pay for... and Snagit is worth every penny.

Answer (score 1):

How about just opening Paint to paste your screen shot and crop it?

Also, if you have Office OneNote it has a lightweight companion utility that can do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, But hitting a screenshot and pasting it on paint is a lot of process,. I'm looking for a shorter process. Because i'll be doing it on a lot of picture..

Answer (score 1):

The two below operate from the browser but are online:

- [Aviary Screen Capture & Quick Launch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/aviary-screen-capture-quick-la/) is free, but you do have to be logged on for it to work.
- [Pixlr Grabber](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pixlr-grabber/) requires Flash to work - free online edit, share, save.

Comment: this worked perfectly for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no easy way of doing this.

You could do it as a two shot process.

Use your current screenshot package to take your screenshots, and then use imagemagick to crop to the specified aspect ratio. You'd need to write some kind of program around the imagemagick as I can't see an easy way of cropping to a specific aspect ratio whilst keeping the width constant.

A second option would be to ask for this as a feature (or make the change yourself) in an open source piece of software like [greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/).

Comment: awesome screenshot tool and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

[Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/) & Snipping Tool (available natively in the Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate and Enterprise editions of Windows 7) are free screen capture utilities that you can try.

Both the tools however cannot resize images

Answer (score 0):

I also need to capture the screen, crop, and resize quickly. I'm proficient with Photoshop, but launching it every time I want to capture the screen is a pain in the neck. I've tried a few software programs that can quickly do it for me. So far the best one I found is [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Their website is bit scary but the software is great and I think is exactly what you are looking for!

Comment: lolz. about their website.. But I decided to go to zScreen. it has all that i need too :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend signing up for [CloudApp](http://www.getcloudapp.com/) and then installing [FluffyApp](http://fluffyapp.com/).

With this all the images are stored on your account and you can select a part of the screen which you want the screenshot for using a keyboard shortcut.