# Screen Capture for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, display, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crop and Capture screen software/plugin for windows7](https://superuser.com/questions/224906/crop-and-capture-screen-software-plugin-for-windows7)

Can anyone recommend a good - not full of adverts - screen capture extension for chrome?
By screen shot I mean full web pages - saved as gif or jpgs or whatever - and not just the current visible section of the screen.

Comment: What kind of feature do you need?  Alt+PrintScreen will take a nice screen shot of the current window.  Are you instead looking to generate thumbnails of web pages?

Comment: Problem is that will only give you the visible portion of the screen.  Screen capture extension by google does the trick.

Comment: Or do you want to make a screenshot in the sense of getting an image of the whole website?

Comment: @slotishtype, right... what is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: Because in that case (and I assumed it) I'd reopen the question because the duplicate doesn't mention full webpage screenshots at all.

Comment: I want the whole web page. I have a gallery of designs that I like and I want to integrate this into my current workflow.  So, I can click a button and save the entire web page as an image.  I found the google screen capture extension as pretty useful.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect your comments.  cheers guys.

Comment: Is the "Save As" (which saves the entire HTML page) function not acceptable?

Comment: Also, there maybe something in the software at http://www.html2jpg.com/

Comment: Snagit mentioned in the linked duplicate does what you ask

Comment: @Mokubai nope, I need an image and not all the associated files.  Got it sorted though, thanks for the suggestions though.